# jQuery - hide div if it doesn't contain one of many classes

Tags: jquery, arrays, comparison

Perhaps there's a simpler way, but I'm fairly new to jQuery, so please bear with me... Essentially, I'm attempting to create an array containing all the values of the selected checkboxes and then hide the divs that do not contain *all* of those values.  Below is some crude markup just to help illustrate what I'm attempting to do.

```
/*** Sample Markup ***/
<div id="item-wrapper">
 <div class="blue red green ivory">Item 32323</div>
 <div class="green red">Item 34234</div>
 <div class="ivory blue green">Item 39403</div>
 <div class="red blue">Item 39923</div>
 <div class="green">Item 32990</div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-filter" name="filter[]" value="red" CHECKED />RED
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-filter" name="filter[]" value="ivory" />IVORY
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-filter" name="filter[]" value="blue" CHECKED />BLUE
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-filter" name="filter[]" value="green" />GREEN
```

In this example, the "RED" and "BLUE" checkboxes are checked.  I'd like to find all the divs within div#item-wrapper that do not contain BOTH red and blue and hide them.  The result, therefore, would be this:

```
<div id="item-wrapper">
 <div class="blue red green ivory">Item 32323</div>
 <div class="green red">Item 34234</div>
 <div class="ivory blue green" style="display:none">Item 39403</div>
 <div class="red blue">Item 39923</div>
 <div class="green" style="display:none">Item 32990</div>
</div>
```

I've been reading about ways to compare arrays, iterate through them, etc., but so far, I've been unsuccessful in finding a solution. Frankly, I'm not entirely clear on what I should search for that would encapsulate what I'm trying to do here, so I'm hoping someone here can help out.

Below is a very lame attempt at trying to get something to work, but it's likely totally useless...

```
var selectedFilters = [];
  $('input.checkbox-filter').live('click',function() {
    $('input.checkbox-filter').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          selectedFilters.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

            $('#item-wrapper div').each(function() {
                var str = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');


                /*** And, this is where I got lost ***/


            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $divs = $('#item-wrapper > div')
var $checks = $('input[name="filter[]"]');
$checks.change(function(){
    var classes = $checks.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value
    }).get();
    if(classes.length){
        $divs.hide().filter('.' + classes.join('.')).show();
    } else {
        $divs.show();
    }
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PUDWX/)

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, you just have to check `.hasClass` for each of the classes:

```
var item = $(this);
selectedFilters.forEach(function(filter) {
    if (!item.hasClass(filter)) {
        item.hide();
    } 
});
```

(Also, make sure `selectedFilters` is declared or cleared inside the "click" handler.)

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYNfF/5/)